Spring Framework broken injection
Who can explain this behaviour in Spring? There is an abstract class:
abstract class BaseRepo {
    @Autowired
    protected lateinit var dsl: DSLContext
    // ....
}

@Repository
class MyRepo : BaseRepo {
    // ...
}

Question: why in case MyRepo is declared as @Repository, the framework does not initialize @Autowired fields – protected lateinit var dsl: DslContext, but if you change @Repository to @Service or @Component, the injection works? This is strange, because @Repository is a subtype of @Component, just at the specification level, but it turns out not, Spring handles them differently.
P.S.
I noticed it on Spring Boot 3, I haven't tested it on Spring Boot 2. Constructor injection - do not suggest

an @Repository will be proxied by default, the proxy won't have any fields filled only the instance it wraps. Kotlin makes things final by default and if you don't open up things, methods will be called on the proxy instead passing on to the wrapped object.This is more of a broken proxy issue (due to either final methods or methods with the wrong visibility). An @Autowired field in Spring will never be null it if is it is either an instance not controlled by Spring or a proxy issue. If Spring cannot satisfy the @Autowired the app won't even start.

I think @Repository is treated differently when handling dependency injection. I just tested this out and the only way I could make this work without a constructor injection is using getter/setter (I'll give the examples in Java but I'm sure you can translate them to whatever JVM language you're using as well):
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public abstract class BaseRepo {

    private DSLContext dsl;

    @Autowired
    protected void setDsl(final DSLContext dsl) {
        this.dsl = dsl;
    }

    protected DSLContext getDsl() {
        return dsl;
    }

}

This might not be a complete answer but maybe it helps you since it keeps the encapsulation and doesn't require constructor injection.
Here's a service example to prove this:
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class SomeService {

    private DSLContext dsl;

    public SomeService(final MyRepo repo) {
        this.dsl = repo.getDsl();
    }

}


As you can see the dsl gets correctly injected and retrieved from the repository (in the image instead of null you see (id=131))
It also works when doing stuff in MyRepo:
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class MyRepo extends BaseRepo {

    public void doSomething() {
        DSLContext dsl = getDsl();
        // dsl will not be null
    }

}

Note: Also keep in mind that Java - Kotlin interoperability is a lie so Spring Boot might not work the same, just look for lambda lazy evaluation to see what I mean.

also, I've tried to reproduce this case in empty project and bean was initialised with @Component and @Repository; link to original issue

unfortunately, setter didn't worked

Would you try the same with Java? The setter problem looks like a Kotlin issue since it works fine in Java, at least you can also specify that on the Spring Boot thread.
